# Writing floats to csvs in python -- truncation error

Tags: python, csv, floating-point, truncate

I'm encountering an issue where float numbers are being truncated in my csv writing process.  This is difficult to replicate, as it happens infrequently across thousands of files, but I need a protection against it.  Here is an example of what the code looks like:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(0, .001, 1000).tolist()
draws_header = ['draw%s'%(x) for x in range(1000)]
final_output = np.array(x)
outfile = open('filepath.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer('filepath')
writer.writerow(first_row)
writer.writerows(final_output)
outfile.close()
```

Based on the output (in which all numbers are necessarily below 1), it looks like the final characters in a small number (ie, "...e-5") are getting lost:

```
draw373         draw374         draw375          draw376    
0.000744        0.003008        0.001566         9.727522
```

Any suggestions on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using numpy's csv writer for this. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.normal(0, .001, 1000)
>>> draws_header = ['draw%s'%(i) for i in range(1000)]
>>> f = open('file.csv', 'w')
>>> np.savetxt(f, np.array(draws_header)[:,None].T, fmt="%s", delimiter="\t")
>>> np.savetxt(f, x[:,None].T, delimiter="\t")
>>> f.close()
```

This serializes the numbers correctly. You can also pass a format string to savetxt to specify how to print your floating point values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Good answer, however it would be cleaner this way:
>>> np.savetxt(f, np.array([draws_header]), fmt="%s", delimiter="\t")
>>> np.savetxt(f, [x], delimiter="\t")

Answer (score 1):

The problem is converting between the decimal representation of the number and the in-memory representation.

You can get more details about python implementation of float's:
http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.float_info

There is also comprehensive tutorial about floating points:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Especially I recommend you section "Representation error"

```
#input
a = 0
for x in xrange(10):
  a += 0.1
print a   
#output
0.9999999999999999
```

If your application requires high precision you can use:

```
#input
from decimal import Decimal
a = Decimal('0.0')
for x in xrange(10):
  a += Decimal('0.1')
print a
#output
1.0
```